# кнопка html (убрать border/окантовка вокруг при нажатии)

Tags: html, css

я использовала

```css
border : none
```

при ***focus***, ***active*** и ***hover*** и все равно я вижу эту черную рамку вокруг кнопки, есть еще состяния кнопки ?

**Подскажите как убрать черную окантовку при нажатии при помощи css.**

как называется это свойство, как изменить его цвет к примеру ?

```css
.clean-label {
  background-color: white;
  color: #29abe2;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clean-label:active {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clean-label:hover {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clean-label:focus {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="clean-label">кнопка без каймы</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите как убрать черную окантовку при нажатии при помощи css.

используйте

```
outline: none
```

```css
.clean-label {
  border:           none;
  background-color: white;
  color:            #29abe2;
  margin-left:      8px;
  text-decoration:  none;
  
  outline:          none;
  cursor:           pointer;
}

.clean-label:hover {
  color:            red;
}
```

```html
<button class="clean-label">кнопка без каймы</button>
```